# Joining an attribute from CSV to JSON results in incorrect output - D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am joining an attribute from a csv to a json on zip code using a double `for` loop. The code runs, but each value in the json receives the same value from the csv. I doubt this is written optimally but that's for another question.

Here's the loop:

```
var zips = us.objects.zip_codes_for_the_usa.geometries;

div.forEach(function(d) {
  zips.forEach(function(e) {
      if (d.zip == e.zip) {
        e.properties.division = d.division;
      }
  })
})
```

Where's the issue? Why does it use the same attribute value?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LAYlylI0FAbfL4F5LnrH?p=preview)

The json file is large, so, unfortunately, the Plunker takes about a minute to load. I currently have it set to `console.log` the value on click of a zip. You'll notice each click returns `AK` which should only be returned in Alaska. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That plunker crashed my browser twice. You don't need the **entire** data array for asking help: please use a `splice`, a `slice` or whatever and trim that array, so we can at least load the plunker.

Comment: Good point. Updated to contain only Florida's data. Clicking on any zip in the US now returns `FL3`.

Comment: There are two shortcomings: one in your code, the other in your data! 1) In `zips` you have a nested property `.properties.zip`; your if-statement therefore needs to be `if (d.zip == e.properties.zip)`. 2) Even if this is corrected, this will never evaluate to true, though, because in your data there are no entries having a match `zip` property in `div` and `zips` respectively.